# Woocommerce related product text

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Hi guys im currently using this in my function.php

```
    // Change WooCommerce "Related products" text

    add_filter('gettext', 'change_rp_text', 10, 3);
    add_filter('ngettext', 'change_rp_text', 10, 3);

    function change_rp_text($translated, $text, $domain)
    {
     if ($text === 'Related products' && $domain === 'woocommerce') {
         $translated = esc_html__('You may also like..', $domain);
     }
     return $translated;
    }
```

It works very well, however i want to add two dots after "You may also like", however it will only return one.. How can i achieve this?